My Pinescript strategy is closing trades immediatly after opening and i cannot understand why
doing my best to learn pinescript. im currently working with a Market Structure shift Strategy and CANNOT understan why these trades are closing immediatly after placing them.
at this stage i simply want to take trades in the direction of the identified MSS and close them on an opposing one.
I have previously grappled with trades opening and closing on every bar and solved it by adding a criteria reset after trade entry. im wondering if that is what has cause it.
code is outlined below.
//@version=5
strategy("Market Structure (working copy)", "Market Structure (working copy)", true, max_labels_count = 500, max_lines_count = 500)

pivot_strength = input.int(3, "Pivot Strength", 1)
show_pivots = input.bool(false, "Show Pivots", inline = "PIV")
highs = input.color(color.blue, "", inline = "PIV")
lows = input.color(#f23645, "", inline = "PIV")
show_bos = input.bool(false, "Show BOS/MSS")
style = input.string("Dashed", "Line Style", options = ['Solid', 'Dashed', 'Dotted'])
enableFilter = input(true,  "Enable Backtesting Range Filtering")
fromDate   = input.time(timestamp("20 Jul 2023 00:00 +0300"), "Start Date")
toDate       = input.time(timestamp("20 Jul 2099 00:00 +0300"), "End Date")
tradeDateIsAllowed = not enableFilter or (time >= fromDate and time <= toDate)
ticks_target = input.int(60, "Ticks Target")
// Times are in UTC


type swing
    int _index = na
    float _val = na

method set_val(swing s, int i, float v) =>
    s._index := i
    s._val := v

method set_na(swing s) =>
    s._index := na
    s._val := na

var swing_high = swing.new()
var swing_low = swing.new()
var temp_hi = swing.new()
var temp_lo = swing.new()

var bool bull = na

sh = false
sl = false

bull_bos = false
bull_mss = false
bear_bos = false
bear_mss = false

var line_style = switch style
    "Solid" => line.style_solid
    "Dashed" => line.style_dashed
    "Dotted" => line.style_dotted
// drawing boxes on the sh and sl's
if not na(ta.pivothigh(high, pivot_strength, pivot_strength))
    swing_high.set_val(bar_index - pivot_strength, high[pivot_strength])
    sh := true // Sh and SL are used for the shapes drawn above and below sl and sh's 
    
if not na(ta.pivotlow(low, pivot_strength, pivot_strength))
    swing_low.set_val(bar_index - pivot_strength, low[pivot_strength])
    sl := true // Sh and SL are used for the shapes drawn above and below sl and sh's 


// ID MSS section 
if not na(swing_high._val)
    if close > swing_high._val 
        mss = (bull == false or na(bull))
        if mss
            bull_mss := true
            temp_hi.set_val(swing_high._index, swing_high._val)
            bear_mss := false  // Reset bear_mss when bull_mss is true
        else
            bull_bos := true
            temp_hi.set_val(swing_high._index, swing_high._val)
        bull := true
        swing_high.set_na()
        
if not na(swing_low._val)
    if close < swing_low._val
        mss = (bull == true or na(bull))
        if mss
            bear_mss := true
            temp_lo.set_val(swing_low._index, swing_low._val)
            bull_mss := false  // Reset bull_mss when bear_mss is true
        else
            bear_bos := true
            temp_lo.set_val(swing_low._index, swing_low._val)
        bull := false
        swing_low.set_na()


// MSS direction ascertained in here. 


if show_bos
    if bull_mss[1] or bull_bos[1]
        line.new(temp_hi._index, temp_hi._val, bar_index - 1, temp_hi._val, style = line_style, color = highs)
        label.new(math.floor(math.avg(temp_hi._index, bar_index - 1)), temp_hi._val, bull_mss[1] ? "MSS" : "BOS", textcolor = highs, color = #ffffff00, style = label.style_label_down)

    if bear_mss[1] or bear_bos[1]
        line.new(temp_lo._index, temp_lo._val, bar_index - 1, temp_lo._val, style = line_style, color = lows)
        label.new(math.floor(math.avg(temp_lo._index, bar_index - 1)), temp_lo._val, bear_mss[1] ? "MSS" : "BOS", textcolor = lows, color = #ffffff00, style = label.style_label_up)

plotshape(show_pivots and sh, style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = highs, offset = -pivot_strength, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(show_pivots and sl, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = lows, offset = -pivot_strength, size = size.tiny)


// Entry conditions
var entry_condition_long = false
var entry_condition_short = false

// Variables to reset MSS conditions one bar later
var bool bull_mss_reset = false
var bool bear_mss_reset = false

// Check for entry based on MSS 
if bull_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades < 1
    entry_condition_long := true

if bear_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades < 1
    entry_condition_short := true

// Entry 
if entry_condition_long and bull_mss
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, 1)

if entry_condition_short and bear_mss  
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, 1)

// Exit conditions
var exit_condition_long = false
var exit_condition_short = false

// Check for exit based on opposing MSS

if bear_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades > 0
    exit_condition_long:= true

if bull_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades > 0
    exit_condition_short:= true


// Exit
if exit_condition_long
    strategy.close("Buy")
if exit_condition_short
    strategy.close("Sell")


AI-generated code is inconsistent, buggy, and unreliable. Artificial Intelligence is very useful in many aspects, but it encodes Pinescript very poorly (for now...).
Delete the var entry_condition & exit_condition
// Check for entry based on MSS 
if bull_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades < 1
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

if bear_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades < 1
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

// Check for exit based on opposing MSS
if bear_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades > 0
    strategy.close("Buy")

if bull_mss and tradeDateIsAllowed and strategy.opentrades > 0
    strategy.close("Sell")


thanks for the feedback - now that you've pointed it out that code is utterly redundant. Sadly I'm now only getting a single entry at the beginning of the period and no close. The upside is I've successfully created my first 'buy and hold' strategy :)

the code now works https://i.imgur.com/Okszd9F.png
